# Maven EAR project won't register Faces Converter

Tags: maven, jsf-2, facelets, converters, ear

My Maven EAR project has two WAR module and one EJB module. There is a FacesConverter class in EJB module and when I try to use it from one of the WAR module it throws an exception. I register this converter with annotation @FacesConverter("org.util.ObjectConverter") use it in a JSF page

javax.servlet.ServletException: Expression Error: Named Object: org.util.ObjectConverter not found.

When ObjectConverter is in WAR module it works fine, but it won't load from the EJB module.

What am I missing here?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you put it in EJB module? Front-end (read: JSF) artifacts should go in WAR module. EJB module should only contain business services which are supposed to be reuseable to front-ends other than JSF, such as JSP/Servlet, Struts2, SpringMVC, JAX-RS, etc. The EJB module should absolutely have **no single line** of `javax.faces.*` import/dependency in the code.

JSF doesn't look for converters (let alone any other JSF related artifacts such as validators, managed beans and Facelets files) in EJB module, but only in WAR module. Just keep them in the WAR module. Whatever code you think need to share between the WAR and EJB modules should be refactored into a separate Java project which end up as a common JAR file in EAR module (note that this should in turn also contain **no** JSF-specific artifacts.

Comment: If only Chichiray agrees with that! :) thanks for your answer, now everything makes sense.